# How to get the list of rooms under an application?

Tags: xmpp, quickblox, tigase

I am using the built in function provided by Quickblox - chatService.listRooms(function(err,result))

When I execute this function - I get just true in the result. When I go to the Console and see the response, it is this -

[image]

So, actually it is fetching the list but not returning in the form of XML/JSON to the function?

How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: This is in QB roadmap. We are currently working on new version, so update should be available soon.

Comment: Is some other method available till the new version is out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your chat plugin to **version 0.9.0**

http://quickblox.com/developers/Web_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Download_Chat_plugin

In new version this was changed. Currently, next functions give the array with objects in response:

- getRoomMembers
- getOnlineUsers
- listRooms
- getRoomInfo

Comment: thanks a lot!... i was fiddling on the sample i downloaded from their site.. so i assumed it was using the latest plugin..
interestingly, the response i got from QB tells me that they are still working on this..anyways thanks again..cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find this method? chatService.listRooms(function(err,result))

If you use Android SDK - there is another method to retrieve a list of all rooms:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Retrieving_rooms

```
QBChatService.getInstance().getRooms(new RoomReceivingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveRooms(List<QBChatRoom> qbChatRooms) {
        for (QBChatRoom room : qbChatRooms) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Received room " + room.getName());
        }
    }
});
```

And it works as expected

Same for iOS:

```
[[QBChat instance] requestAllRooms];

- (void)chatDidReceiveListOfRooms:(NSArray *)_rooms{
    NSLog(@"Did receive list of rooms: %@", _rooms);
}
```

Please provide a bit more info what programming language and SDK do you use

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But i am looking for the solution in javascript api